# scope value not updating on ajax response

Tags: angularjs

I have an `ng-if` that depends on `changePW` scope var in my controller. I need to use `ng-if` rather than `show` because hides a set of `inputs` for a form, which have error checking. I don't want the error checking on that section if it shouldn't be shown.

The `ng-if` works fine at first, but when the user updates their profile, and I get a response, I call `$scope.reset()` to set `changePW` back to false. This doesn't seem to be removing the `inputs` within that `div` though. Why is this? It doesn't seem to be updating the `$scope.changePW` on the `$http` response.

HTML:

```
<p class="toggle" ng-click="changePW = !changePW">{{ (!changePW) ? 'Change Password' : 'Enter new password info:' }}</p>

changePW {{ changePW }} // False to start. But changes when I click to show the section. This stays as True when the response returns and "reset()" is called.
<div ng-if="changePW">
     ...
```

Controller:

```
//initialize $scope values 
$scope.reset();
...
//update profile
Me.updateProfile($rootScope.me).then(function (res) {
        alertify.success('User profile updated!');
        $scope.reset(); //reset changePW to rehide that part of the form

...
$scope.reset = function () {
    $rootScope.safeApply(function () {
        $scope.changePW = false;
    });
};
```

Comment: The safeApply() function probably doesn't do what it should. What does it do? Why don't you just do `$scope.changePW = false;`?

Comment: Any special reason as to why you are using safeApply?

Comment: @JBNizet safe apply just runs apply after it ensures digest cycle is complete. I did that to make sure the scope change would be updated. I've also tried without apply and it doesnt work

Comment: Are you sure request is succeeding? Are there any other child scopes involved? Note that `ng-if` itself creates child scope